# Dilithium signature scheme and timing attacks – Does the running time actually depend on the secret key?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, side-channel-attack, timing-attack, dilithium

The paper [“CRYSTALS – Dilithium: Digital Signatures from Module Lattices”](https://cryptojedi.org/papers/dilithium-20170627.pdf)  (by Léo Ducas, Tancrède Lepoint, Vadim Lyubashevsky, Peter Schwabe, Gregor Seiler, and Damien Stehlé) introduces a digital signature scheme based on lattices.

However, it worries me for two reasons:

1. There is no proof of post-quantum security.
2. There is no proof that the running time does not depend on the secret key.

The first appears to be a technical limitation of the proof technique and unlikely to lead to a practical attack, but the second one is definitely exploitable if my fear is real.

Does the running time actually depend on the secret key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The running time does not depend on the secret key. All multiplications, additions, and modular reductions can be implemented to be constant-time.

Diving in to the details:

- The probability of the `goto` in line 11 of the signing algorithm is independent of $s_1$, $s_2$ (the probability is in equation *(4)*).
- The `goto` in line 13 is also independent of $s_1$, $s_2$ because the use of $s_2$ in line 12 can be replaced with an expression that does not use $s_2$ (as in equation *(1)* ) in which all variables have distributions independent of $s_1$, $s_2$.

Comment: This is a very interesting point. Could you please elaborate further? Basically, if the rejection probability is independent from the secret key, then does this count as a constant-time implementation?
On one hand, for a same signing key, the signing time varies due to rejection sampling.
OTOH, for all possible signing keys, this variation stays constant - it's hard to see what useful information is leaked.

Comment: @zhenfeizhang Please don't get me wrong, but you've got a perfectly new question there… which I think is [worth being asked on its own](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You'll most probably earn some reputation via upvotes by asking it too. ;)